# Exercise environment taking another page when there isn't enough space

Tags: environments

I have a small problem using this exercise environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem{exercice}{Exercice}%
{ % frame stuff
    enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,
    colframe=blue,
    borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{green!25!blue},
    left=0.2cm,
    % title stuff
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-2mm},
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxed title style={boxrule=.4pt,sharp corners}}{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercice}{title}{ex.mylabel}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{exercice}
\end{document}
```

When there isn't enough space, it takes space in another page

[image]

While I want it to begin in the first page and continue (if there is still text) in the other page

Comment: You can add the `breakable` option to your `\newtcbtheorem` to allow it to break across pages. Or you can `\enlargethispage{<dimen>}` (where `<dimen>` is some quantity like `1cm`) to make the page a little bit bigger to try to fit in a single page.

Comment: Can you please show me the code with the breakable option ? I'm beggining with LaTeX and don't know how ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `breakable` option to your `\newtcbtheorem`. But doing only this will make the box behave differently if it's broken across pages.

Ulrike Fischer's comment helps us fix this: Replace `frame empty, interior empty` by `frame hidden, interior hidden`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem{exercice}{Exercice}%
{ % frame stuff
    breakable,% <<< Here
    enhanced,
    % frame empty,interior empty, <<< Change this
    frame hidden,interior hidden,% <<< By this
    colframe=blue,
    borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{green!25!blue},
    left=0.2cm,
    % title stuff
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-2mm},
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxed title style={boxrule=.4pt,sharp corners}}{exercise}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{exercice}{title}{ex.mylabel}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{exercice}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

but the box becomes different when broken, and I really don't know how to fix it `:/`

Comment: Thanks ! In-deed, the box becomes different ! I'm hopping for another solution ...

Comment: @Solarwitness Sorry, I'm no `tcolorbox` expert... Maybe wait a little to see if someone provides a better answer than mine. If not you can always ask a new question :)

Comment: Use `frame hidden,interior hidden,` instead of empty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer And here we have our `tcolorbox` expert :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Solarwitness If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓), so that users that find your question in the future will know it solves the problem :)